# Create image grid - bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I'm trying to create an **image grid** with that little space between columns equal to the image below:

[image: grid]

The problem is that I can not make the right margin(red line), image below shows the problem:

[image]

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/castordida/0zy7qd5m/

```html
<div class="container gridhome mt-5 mb-5 p-0">
 <div class="row" style="height:469px;">
  <div class="col-sm-8 h-100" style="background-color:#000;">
   <span class="categoria"><a href="#1">test</a></span>
   <h3>TESTE</h3>
   <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 p-0">
   <div class="col-sm-12 h-50 p-0">
    <div class="h-100 ml-1" style="background-color:#919191;">
     <span class="categoria"><a href="#">test</a></span>
     <h3>TESTE</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 h-50 p-0">
    <div class="h-100 ml-1 mt-1" style="background-color:#919191;">
     <span class="categoria"><a href="#">test</a></span>
     <h3>TESTE</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row mt-1" style="height:234.5px;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 p-0">
   <div class="h-100" style="background-color:#919191;">
    <span class="categoria"><a href="#1">test</a></span>
    <h3>TESTE</h3>
    <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 p-0">
   <div class="h-100 ml-1" style="background-color:#919191;">
    <span class="categoria"><a href="#">test</a></span>
    <h3>TESTE</h3>
    <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 h-100 p-0">
   <div class="h-100 ml-1" style="background-color:#919191;">
    <span class="categoria"><a href="#">test</a></span>
    <h3>TESTE</h3>
    <a href="#" class="inteira"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you provide a working fiddle to work on, I can't reproduce your issue regarding your screenshot https://www.bootply.com

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/castordida/0zy7qd5m/

Comment: UPDATED, added the jsfiddle, thanks Pimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's due to the fact there is a gab between your picture at right... But the fixed height doesn't mention it...

There are many ways to correct this...

---

**First** : https://jsfiddle.net/y0x7kpza/

Add an overflow:hidden to the first .row

---

**Second**: https://jsfiddle.net/d0a52xwk/

Reaffect the height of the two div on the right in taking care of the margin-top of these elements.

```
.h-50-bis{
  height:calc(50% - 0.125rem);
}
```

Comment: awsome, i'm going to use the second one so the two images are the same size, thank you.